# Uncertain number objects owned by another object

Tags: php, oop

I have a Project class/object that needs to have (own) an uncertain number of Phase objects.

I don't know the number of phases the project object will have when it is created, so I didn't want to put Phase object creation in the constructor function of Project.

My classes:

```
class Project {
     //some properties
}

class Phase {
     public $property;
}
```

And I'd like to do this:

```
 $foo = $myProject->phase01->property;
 $bar = $myProject->phase06->property;
 //etc...
```

Comment: You could be bloating myProject as the app becomes larger. No need to call myProject on each call. Have a factory return an instance and save this in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use dynamic properties.

If the **phases** are a collection, would treat them as such, it could come handy later on. [E.g.](https://repl.it/FaXx/0):

```
class Project {

    private $phases = [];

     public function __get($property)
     {
        // if begins with "phase" and some number
        if ( preg_match("/^phase(\d+)$/", $property, $matches) ) {
            // if is set already, we return it
            if ( isset($this->phases[$matches[1]]) ) {
                return $this->phases[$matches[1]];
            }
            // if it isn't, it isn't :)
            return null;    
        }
     }

    public function __set($property, $value)
    {
        if ( preg_match("/^phase(\d+)$/", $property, $matches) ) {
            $this->phases[$matches[1]] = $value;
        }
    }

    public function addPhase(Phase $phase, $phase_number = null)
    { 
        if ($phase_number !== null) {
            $this->phases[$phase_number] = $phase;
        }
        else {
            $this->phases[] = $phase;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPhases()
    {
         return $this->phases;
    }

    // etc
}

class Phase {
  public $property = "";
  public function __construct($property) {
    $this->property = $property;
  }
}

$myProject = new Project();

$myProject->phase1 = new Phase('startup');

$myProject
      ->addPhase(new Phase('build'))
      ->addPhase(new Phase('cleanup'));

foreach ($myProject->getPhases() as $key => $phase) {
     echo "Phase $key: {$phase->property}", "\n";
}
```

Comment: I've played with your code to make sure I understand it. This is the re-direction I think I was needing. I've also run across `SplObjectStorage` and am wondering if I should be using something like this to store my Phase objects inside the Project object?

Comment: Not very familiar with that one. But I wouldn't over-complicate things unnecessarily. Start with something you understand, and build from there.

Comment: Noticed a couple of bugs/typos in my code. updated and linked to repl version.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't use the magical `__set` and `__get` methods. I just left them there because they were part of your question. But I'd go with a regular getter/setter to access the collection.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement one of [php's magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php), in particular [`__get`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get)

```
<?php

class Project {
     //some properties
     public function __get($property)
     {
        // if begins with "phase" and some number
        if ( preg_match("/^phase\d+$/", $property) === 1 ) {
            if ( !isset($this->$property) ) {
                $this->$property = new Phase;
            }

            return $this->$property;
        }
     }
}

class Phase {
     public $property;
}


$myProject = new Project;

//And I'd like to do this:

 $foo = $myProject->phase01->property;
 $bar = $myProject->phase06->property;
 //etc...
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff. And what if I'm stuck w php 5? Either way, am I approaching my problem the right way with respect to design?

Comment: @Ben I've downgraded it for PHP 5. As for approaching your problem, you didn't really specify it to clearly. Perhaps if you explained better why you were trying to do something, then it would be easier to advise an approach. If I had to guess, I'd suspect you'd be better off with an iterable collection like an array which would hold all the phases.

Comment: I think you correctly understood what I was trying to get at - and Yivi provided an example of how to do that. I've also run across the `SplObjectStorage` class and am wondering if that will work for this type of problem.